# Multinomial likelihood for large number of groups

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, likelihood

I am trying to investigate the following problem using multinomial likelihoods and could really do with some advice regarding its appropriateness and implementation in R.

A sequence is generated by selecting with replacement from a bag of n differently coloured balls and consists of the number of occurrences of each colour in the selection (i.e. each sequence is a vector of length n with each element a count corresponding to the number of occurrences of a particular colour in the sequence). The process is then repeated a number of times to generate a group of unique sequences (duplicate sequences are rejected).

If a single sequence is selected at random as the test subject and a multinomial model is generated for each of the other sequences, using the colour count proportions as probabilities, can the likelihood be calculated for each multinomial model in the group using the test sequence as the data and would the greatest likelihood indicate the most alike sequence from the group?

I have tried implementing this in R but am struggling with a couple of points.

1. Calculating the likelihood fails if the number of colours is large since the factorial term falls out of bounds.
2. If the number of occurrences of each colour relative to the total number of colours is small then the probability is small and the product of the $p^x$ terms tends to zero.

I hope this makes sense and somebody is able to offer some advice.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by taking the log-likelihood and using the lfactorial function in R (Solved by people on the Talk Stats forum).

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you should work with log probabilities rather than probabilities themselves, since multiplying small doubles is very imprecise. Multiplication then becomes addition, which is much more accurate. If you need to sum probabilities you need a stable "`logsumexp`" function, see [http://machineintelligence.tumblr.com/post/4998477107/the-log-sum-exp-trick] for example. SlowlyFailing is absolutely correct about using `lfactorial` (i.e. `lgamma` really) rather than `factorial`.